# SAP GUI Scripting - Create PDF from print screen in pywin32

Tags: vba, pywin32, pywinauto, sap-gui

I am trying to script a SAP GUI process which looks at a custom report. The report can be "printed" and then saved as a PDF. However, once you specify "LOCL" as the output device and select the check box it goes to a print screen that isn't included in the GUI scripting output.

Does anyone know how to write script in VBA or Python to continue? I have attached a screenshot of the print dialog box that pops up that I can't figure out how to work in VBA or Python. Then the second dialog that comes up is asking for filepath and filename.

It should be possible with pywin32 but I can't figure it out.
[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should be much easier with pywinauto: `pip install pywinauto`. The code should look like this:

```
from pywinauto import Application

# handle Print dialog
app = Application(backend="win32").connect(title="Print") # timeout (in sec.) is optional
app.PrintDialog.OK.click() # or .click_input() for real click
app.PrintDialog.wait_not("visible") # to make sure it is closed

# handle Save dialog
app = Application(backend="win32").connect(title="Save Print Output As") # maybe not needed if it is the same process
app["Save Print Output As"].FileNameEdit.set_text(file_path) # or .type_keys(file_path, with_spaces=True)
app["Save Print Output As"].SaveButton.click() # or .click_input()
app["Save Print Output As"].wait_not("visible")
```